# Retrieving URL of an IFrame in grails/groovy

Tags: java, javascript, grails

I am creating an application using Grails/Groovy that will contain an iFrame which the user can browse in. I would like to be able to store the URL that the iFrame is currently on in a string property (currentSession) on the users account so it will automatically return to this page the next time the user logs in..

I just don't know how to retreive the URL of the iFrame so it can be saved to currentSession whenever the user logs out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It must be done using JavaScript, for example:

```
var frameUrl = document.getElementById('_content').src
```

where `_content` is ID of target frame. `frameUrl` will contain URL of document in frame

I guess you know how to send it to server?

Comment: Thanks, no I'm unsure of how to send the frameUrl back to the server

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to grab the iframe URL with javascript and post it to a Grails controller, which has access to the current session.

Perhaps something like this (asuming you're using jQuery as your Javascript framework):

```
<g:javascript>
     var iframe = $('#iframeid')
     var url = iframe.attr('src')

     $.post('${createLink(controller: 'some_controller', action: 'some_action')}', {ur: url})
</g:javascript>
```

and then make a controller - ask if you need help with that :-)